# Applying mutate to multiple columns and rows in dplyr

Tags: r, rounding, dplyr

A pretty simple question but has me dumbfounded.

I have a table and am trying to round each column to 2 decimal places using mutate_all (or another dplyr function). I know this can be done with certain apply functions but I like the dplyr/tidyverse frame work.

```
DF = data.frame(A = seq(from = 1, to = 2, by = 0.0255),
           B = seq(from = 3, to = 4, by = 0.0255))

Rounded.DF = DF%>%
  mutate_all(funs(round(digits = 2)))
```

This does not work however and just gives me a 2 in every column. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a "dot" in the round function. The dot is a  placeholder for where mutate_all should place each column that you are trying to manipulate.

```
Rounded.DF = DF%>%
  mutate_all(funs(round(., digits = 2)))
```

To make it more intuitive you can write the exact same thing as a custom function and then reference that function inside the mutate_all:

```
round_2_dgts <- function(x) {round(x, digits = 2)}

Rounded.DF = DF%>%
  mutate_all(funs(round_2_dgts))
```